# Make python create a new object

Tags: python, python-3.x

So lets say, that I have a class: test(a, b, c) and I want python(v3) to create random objects that use this class. The only idea i was able to come up with, is to create all the objects first with None value, put them in a list and then use this list to create the objects. So something in this direction (not a real code):

```
a=None
b=None
c=None
list=[a, b, c]
for i in list:
    i=test(something random, something random, something random)
```

the problem with this solution is that in this way I can only have len(list) of those random objects and I have to create them myself upfront. Is there a way for python(v3) to create an object all by himself, so that I can potentially create an infinite number of  those random objects?

Side note: I tried to find it out by myself but, since I just shortly started to teach myself programming, it might very well be that I could not find an answer because I don´t know how to formulate it correctly or maybe even saw it but not recognized it as a solution.

Thanks upfront for every bit of help and sorry if my English is not perfect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create individual named objects initialized to `None`, just create an empty list and add to it in a loop.

```
seq = []
for i in range(100):
    seq.append(SomeRandomObject())
```

Or use a list comprehension.

```
seq = [SomeRandomObject() for i in range(100)]
```